# Batman Arkham city line launcher

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm stuck at a particular part of Batman: Arkham City, because the Line Launcher isn't an option in my gadgets.  How do I get the Line Launcher?

Here's the part I'm stuck on:

Comment: Just be patient and keep playing the game. Don't jump the gun.

Answer (score 8):

At a certain point in the game, after you've chased the Ra's al Ghul assassin, Batman will contact Alfred to have the line launcher sent to Arkham City.  Has this event occurred yet?  You'll then have to go and pick it up.  This will be a primary objective for you.

If Alfred hasn't sent the launcher, you'll have to continue with the primary objectives before this event will occur.  You can't get past this area until you have this gadget.

Comment: I undertand...I will maybe have to reset my last chekpoint......Thanx a lot ;)))